# Using xp_dirtree in remote server in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

trying to list the files from folder which is in remote server. xp_dirtree is listing files from local folder but showing empty for folder which is in remote server. I did google on this but did not get the solution to fix.

Thanks in Advance
Charles

Comment: You (your SQL server account) may not have enough permissions to list remote computer files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XP_Dirtree by default checks local server folders..

If the folders are in remote server, you will have to pass UNC paths like below

```
\\dir\folder1
```

**References:**
http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2012/11/how-to-use-xpdirtree-to-list-all-files.html